# Uncaught TypeError: in JS

Tags: javascript

I am getting:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> at newTipCalc.js:4"

Can anybody tell what is wrong:

```
var johnTipCal = {
    name: 'John Smith',
    bills: [124,48,268,180,42],
    bill : this.bills[0]    

};

console.log(johnTipCal.bill);
```

Comment: this.bills is undefined

Comment: @TSR
i have already defined bills on above line

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @Harmandeep,
Somewhat yes , but what should be the way to assign it

Comment: You cannot access prop of an object within the object itself during initialization

Comment: var bills = [124,48,268,180,42]; var johnTipCal = { name: 'John Smith', bills, bill : bills[0]
};

Comment: @AnuragSharma, I have provided a way you can achieve it. Have a look!

Comment: @TSR:
But can i access the properties via functions:

var john = {
    name : 'John Smith',
    mass :  70,
    height : 1.8,
    bmiCalc: function(){
        this.bMI = this.mass/(this.height * this.height);
        return this.bMI;
        }
};

Answer (score 3):

As you are defining variable it is not in the scope, if you want to access that `bills` then you will have to initialise variable first and then re assign values as follows:

```
let johnTipCal = {
  bills: [124,48,268,180,42],
}
johnTipCal = {
    ...johnTipCal,
    name: 'John Smith',
    bill : johnTipCal.bills[0]    

};

console.log(johnTipCal.bill);
```

Answer (score 1):

this.bills is undefined.
You need to check that it is set to a least an empty array

var bills = [124,48,268,180,42];
var johnTipCal = {
name: 'John Smith',
bills,
bill : bills[0]
};

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the property which is undefined yet . So what you can do is , create the object without bill property .
Later once it is created you can add , the bill property to it.

```js
var johnTipCal = {
    name: 'John Smith',
    bills: [124,48,268,180,42]
};

johnTipCal.bill = johnTipCal.bills[0] 
console.log(johnTipCal);
```